# C++ help class inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, syntax-error

I have made one parent class and one inherited class. In main when I gave the inherited class an object an error would show up such as "object not accessible". Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Parents{
protected:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    void getInfo(int hAge, string hName)
    {
        name = hName;
        age = hAge;
        cout << "Their son name is " << name << endl;
        cout << "He is " << age << " years old" << endl;
        cout << "His hair is red" << endl;
        cout << "He is a boy" << endl;
    }
};

class Son : public Parents{
    Son(){
        name = "John";
        age = 25;
    }
};



int main(){
    Son boy; //object not accessible

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to make constructor public

Comment: there is also another problem. When I call boy.getInfo(), it says too few function called. Why is that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of class Son is private by default .make it public.

```
class Son : public Parents{
public:
    Son(){
        name = "John";
        age = 25;
    }
};
```

---

Update:

```
class Parents{
protected:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    // Call this when you have not already assigned value to age and name
    void getInfo(int hAge, string hName)
    {
        name = hName;
        age = hAge;
        cout << "Their son name is " << name << endl;
        cout << "He is " << age << " years old" << endl;
        cout << "His hair is red" << endl;
        cout << "He is a boy" << endl;
    }

    // Call this when age and name already have values.
    void getInfo()
    {
        cout << "Their son name is " << name << endl;
        cout << "He is " << age << " years old" << endl;
        cout << "His hair is red" << endl;
        cout << "He is a boy" << endl;
    }
};

class Son : public Parents{
public:
    Son(){
        name = "John";
        age = 25;
    }
};



int main(){
    Son boy; 
    boy.getInfo(); // Will call 2nd method
    boy.getInfo(13,"First method"); // will call 1st method
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank, there is also another problem. When I call boy.getInfo(), it says too few function called. Why is that @Nishant Kumar

Comment: your function `void getInfo(int hAge, string hName)` need two values. So when you are calling boy.getInfo() with no parameter it doesn't match with method signature. either change the method signature or try method overloading

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor of class `Son` is private. Therefore, an object of class `Son` cannot be default constructed from outside the class like you are trying with `Son boy;` in you `main` function. Make the constructor public.

Answer (score 0):

The member inside class is *private* to access by default.
So if you want to define your own constructor and you want to access it, you should specify it to be *public*